# Alert when backspace is pressed inside textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have a grid with three read-only columns. Whenever user goes in there and try to edit by pressing backspace, I need to alert by giving a message. I am using this script and it doesn't work? Can anyone correct me?

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#txtCode').bind('keypress', function (e) {
          if (e.which == 8) {
              alert('The column is read-only and is not editable');
          }  
      }         
  });
```

Comment: You're missing `)` `in keypress` just a simple syntax error!

Comment: Regarding the purpose of your code, why display the alert only on backspace? The user may try to edit by adding new characters, or may select existing text and type to replace it, etc.

Comment: @nnnnnn: If so can I use || followed by the list of keycode in the script? if (e.which==8 || e.which==46)

Comment: Well yes you can, but it would be impractical to list out all keys the user could possibly press. And what about changes made via methods that don't involve the keyboard (e.g., the Edit menu or drag'n'drop)? Do you not just have a `readonly` attribute on the elements in question?

Comment: @nnnnnn: Honestly I don't have solution for that. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

instead of `keypress` try with `keyup` or `keydown` with `.on()` method:

```
$('#txtCode').on('keyup keydown', function (e) {
```

You can bind multiple events like this too.

and one more thing closing of `$('#txtCode')` seems to be missing `});`

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#txtCode').on('keyup keydown', function (e) {
       if (e.which == 8) {
         alert('The column is read-only and is not editable');
       }  
     }); //<----");" this is the closing you misssed this         
  });
```

[See the fiddle in action](http://jsfiddle.net/t8VvQ/1/)

Comment: Have you referenced the jquery library in the head? What error is in browser's console? if console says `jQuery or $` is undefined, then it means you have to give a reference of the jquery library first in the head.

Comment: @user3003821 - the id attribute is supposed to be unique. You have three columns and (presumably) multiple rows, so it would be invalid html if all such fields have the same `id="txtCode"` and `$('#txtCode')` would likely only find the first one - try changing them to `class="txtCode"` and use `$(".txtCode")`.

Comment: @Jai: I have reference jquery library. There is no action when I press the key in textbox.

Answer (score 1):

If this is all the code you are testing, you weren't closing the function properly, annotated in my posted code. Also use `keyup` instead of `keypress`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtCode').bind('keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 8) {
            alert('The column is read-only and is not editable');
        }
    }); /*<-- You weren't closing your function properly*/
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhPZU/)

You do indeed need to add a `return false` statement to ensure the character doesn't get deleted anyway. I also took it a step further and extended jQuery with a `preventKeyUsage` method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.preventKeyUsage = function (key, message) {
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).on('keydown', function (e) {
                return (e.keyCode === key) ? (function () {
                    alert(message);
                    return false;
                })() : true;
            });
        });
    };

    $('#txtCode').preventKeyUsage(8, 'The column is read-only and is not editable');
});
```

[New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhPZU/10/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `});` of `keypress`. google chrome have issues with keypress, u can try keydown instead

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#txtCode').bind('keydown', function (e) {

  if (e.which == 8) {
  alert('The column is read-only and is not editable');
  }  
  });

  });
```

To use delete ,arrows, backspace keys in Chrome you must use keydown. keypress on these keys work only in Firefox and Opera.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/76sfU/2/)

Comment: please check at left side which jquery file u r referencing.its working on my machine. ya its nor working in chrome use keydown instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtCode').on('keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 8) {
            alert('The column is read-only and is not editable');
        }
    }); 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yhPZU/5/) (Working on Firefox & Chrome)

Comment: @user3003821 add jquery library in head section . see fiddle it working

Comment: @PrasathK - Why wouldn't it work in Chrome specifically? Which browsers would it work in, and why?

Comment: @nnnnnn See here http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/KeyPress-KeyDown-KeyUp-The-Difference-Between-Javascript-Key-Events.aspx

Comment: @Prasath K : I'm checking in IE 8

Comment: @user3003821 Use `keyup` or `keydown` event rather than `keypress`

Answer (score 0):

Working code is:

**Java Script Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtCode').bind('keypress keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 8) {
            alert('The column is read-only and is not editable');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code

```
<input type="text" id="txtCode" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtCode').bind('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 8) {
            alert('The column is read-only and is not editable');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yhPZU/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textbox').keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 8){
        alert("Backspace not allowed..");
        return false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xF9jL/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can probably solve the underlying issue by either not using an element that accepts input, or by using the disabled attribute:

```
<textarea name="example" disabled>Some text</textarea>
```

If you are posting back to the sever, you should assume the user *has* edited the field, no matter what you do to prevent it.

Answer (score -1):

`keypress` event won't give keycodes for all keys in all browsers . Better use `keyup` or `keydown` event which gives keycode for all keys in all browsers

In order to understand the difference between keydown and keypress, it is useful to understand the difference between a "character" and a "key". A "key" is a physical button on the computer's keyboard while a "character" is a symbol typed by pressing a button.  In theory, the keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed or released, while the keypress event represents a character being typed. The implementation of the theory is not same in all browsers.